# java project.useing file for calculate with property

Tags: java

I have a file with 8 gig data with three columns and many rows. Every column has an integer.

I tried to calculate numbers of rows with this property:

```
Ri.colm1=Rj.colm1&&Ri.colm2=Rj.colm2 && Ri.colm3<>Rj.colm3
```

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problems are you running into? Adding some code will help us understand what you're asking, because right now it's not very clear.

Comment: What is your question? How does this code relate to the problem you're trying to solve? What is the type of file you're working with? Can you give us some sample data?

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20043663/2037229) help